# Elasticsearch query with fields giving subset of results

Tags: elasticsearch

I am new to Elasticsearch. This is the how my document look like :

```
_source : 
{

"name": "this is my title",
"address" : "1300 S Belmont Road"
"ID= : 54000"
}
```

When i run this query :

Query 1 :

```
"query": {
   "filtered": {
      "query": {
         "query_string": {
            "query": "*Belmont*",
            "fields": ["name^5", "address^4","ID^3"]
         }
      },
      "filter": {...}
   }
}
```

I get 51 results

Query 2:

But this one gives 123 results :

```
"query": {
   "filtered": {
      "query": {
         "query_string": {
            "query": "*Belmont*",
                    }
      },
      "filter": {...}
   }
}
```

Why is it that the queries give different results even thogh I am Running the query on all the fields in Query 1

Mappings :

Address and Name are both string and "not_analyzed"

Comment: I don't see if you tried to do any kind of debugging here. For starters you may want to examine the content of the documents that are returned by the second query but not by the first query.

Comment: can you post your mappings?

Comment: @ChintanShah25 Updated the post with the mappings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the way [_all field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-all-field.html) works. Your first query is looking for `*Belmont*` in specified fields with specific **analyzer honored**. It is internally converted to bool query and matched with each field individually.

Since address is `not_analyzed`, *1300 S Belmont Road* will be stored as it is but `_all` field will have space delimited words with standard analyzer applied like *1300*, *s* , *belmont* etc. From the Doc

> The _all field is a special catch-all field which concatenates the
>   values of all of the other fields into one big string, using space as
>   a delimiter, which is then analyzed and indexed, but not stored.

so your second query operates on `_all` field and gives you more results.

Also your first query **wont** match `"address" : "1300 S Belmont Road"` as by default it will be [lowercased](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#_wildcards) while using `wildcard` so it will search for belmont and wont find it. You can change this behavior with `lowercase_expanded_terms` which is true by default. Try this

```
"query": {
   "filtered": {
      "query": {
         "query_string": {
            "query": "*Belmont*",
            "fields": ["name^5", "address^4","ID^3"],
            "lowercase_expanded_terms" : false
         }
      },
      "filter": {...}
   }
}
```

You might get more results depending on how you have stored names and address.

Hope this helps!